# Sort an array (looking a specific value) based on another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array of options, and some value of an internal array is the "ID"

```
[options] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 1088
        [label] => John
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 1089
        [label] => Peter
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 1050
        [label] => Mary
    )
    ....
```

On the other hand, I have this array:

```
$array_sort = array(1089, 1050, 1088, ...);
```

I would like the options array of the first array is sorted (looking the "id") based on the `$array_sort`.

I know how to do it in a very dirty way (with a lot of loops and temporary arrays), but I guess there's some smart solution of array_* functions to do this.

Thank you !

Comment: Thank you for the edition, @Qirel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to limit the options to only those in the sorted array, then [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort them based on their position in the `$array_sort` array using [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
$sorted = array_filter($options, function($arr) use($array_sort) {
    return in_array($arr['id'], $array_sort);
});
usort($sorted, function($a, $b) use($array_sort) {
    return array_search($a['id'], $array_sort) - array_search($b['id'], $array_sort);
});
// $sorted should now be the sorted array
```

Comment: $sorted returns just 1 :-(

Comment: Sorry, it sorts the array in-place. I'll edit the code.

Comment: I can't edit, but you missed the "use ($array_sort)" in the two functions in order to get the array_sort right scope, since it's outside the functions ;-)  and IT WORKS !! THANK YOU

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added it. I guess that's what happens when you try to write code in the answer box.